# I want to extract data using jQuery XML parsing tools, but it doesn't work and seems to block when it comes to ".find('...').each(..."

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

I followed what I Web site suggested to do and I ended up with my script not working properly! And even Firebug doesn't show any error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "server.xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        complete : function(data, status) {
                            var products = data.responseXML;

                            $(products).find('product').each(function(){
                                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                                var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                                var price = $(this).find('price').text();
                                alert("id:" + id + " ; name:" + name + " ; price:" + price);
                            });

                        }
                });
            });
```

Here's the XML file:

I also put the same thing as in their example:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product id="1">
        <name>Eau</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
    <product id="2">
        <name>Pain</name>
        <price>0.70</price>
    </product>
    <product id="3">
        <name>Gateaux</name>
        <price>5</price>
    </product>
</products>

Everything seems to be blocking when it reaches "$(xml).find('...').each(function() {});" and I can't seem to be able to find a way to resolve.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        var products = data.responseXML;
```

jQuery already returns responseXML:

```
var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "",
xml = type === "xml" || !type && ct.indexOf("xml") >= 0,
data = xml ? xhr.responseXML : xhr.responseText;
```

Try just manipulating `data` directly.